# How to fade in and out buttons except for the text in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a button that fades in and out when mouseEnter and mouseLeave.. But my problem is that, the text or content fades in and out also.. I want it to stay.. or is it possible to make the border fade in and out only? not the whole button?

I have this code :

```
    private void Button_MouseLeave_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button c = (Button)sender;
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        c.BeginAnimation(Button.OpacityProperty, animation);
    }

    private void Button_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button c = (Button)sender;
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        c.BeginAnimation(Button.OpacityProperty, animation);
    }
```

Comment: The dirty lame way? Put a rectangle and a label in the same grid spot. Fade the rectangle. If you liked it, put a ring on it and make it a user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to put one more label over the button instead of inside the button. Put your content in that label  with label background-color as transparent and apply fade-in/out logic on your button.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the below Style to get your requirement.

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>

</Window.Resources>
```

Above things are going to be resources which was referenced with its Key. It is not mandatory to be in Window's Resources. It should in the Resource of its peer control, so can place it in `Grid's Resources` also, No problem.

Below Style can also be in the above resources since it was targeted to All the Buttons(If it was targeted directly, this style will apply for all the buttons in that particular window). If this style need to apply only for a particular Button means, you can directly post it inside the `<Button.Style>` *below style* `</Button.Style>`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:1" Value="0">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me, where do i post this codes? inside window tag or the grid tag? sorry my first time..

Comment: Post these codes in the Resources of Window `Window.Resources` where the Button is present.

Comment: when i post it, it has so many errors.. I paste it inside my grid.. am i doing it wrong? how do i do it, i can't understand. Please help .. thanks..

Comment: check the updated answer.. please mark it as answer if it helps you else feel free to let me know for further clarification.